# loc not functioning correctly in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe, which has a bunch of ID name pairs in it.  I create it by doing the following:

```
market_df = pd.DataFrame(markets_info['markets'])

market_df.astype(dict(id=int, name=str))
```

I received ID numbers from a process and I need to grab the associated name to that ID.  I have tried creating an index on the ID and then parsing it, but that doesn't seem to set the ID correctly.

I now am trying to do the following: `exch_name = MARKET_IDS.loc[MARKET_IDS['id'] == exchange_id, 'name']`
I have verified that `exchange_id` is also of type `int`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is because you left out some crucial information from this, but from what it sounds like in your post you're not really altering `market_df` at all, as your second line is not an assignment. It should read `market_df = market_df.astype(dict(id=int, name=str))`

Comment: I have not left out any crucial information.  does market_df.astype(dict(id=int, name=str)) not modify the underlying dataframe?  I was under the impression it does.

Comment: No it returns the casted data